# WCF/Asmx dando timeout mas hardware do servidor está sussegado

Tags: wcf, integração, asmx

Boa noite.

Eu tenho uma aplicação que é integrada com mais de cem outras aplicações através de webservices, onde eu utilizo bastante threads para comunicação entre elas. Essa minha aplicação é utilizada por outras aplicações através de uma dll hoje. Estou tentando migrar essa dll para um serviço, para isso criei um serviço WCF (já tentei asmx tbm). O problema é que conforme vão entrando as requisições esse serviço começa a aumentar muito o timeout de resposta até começar a dar timeout em tudo. O que é estranho é que o hardware (memoria e cpu) estão abaixo dos 30% de consumo, então eu acredito que o problema são as threads lançadas, ou alguma configuração de iis ou do wcf/asmx. Queria saber se alguem já passou por isso ou tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso.

Obrigado.

Comment: Nikolas, como está os valores de `InstanceContextMode`, `ConcurrencyMode` e os valores de `Throttling`, tambem gostaria de saber se as suas aplicações clientes realizam requisições simultâneas internamente (a mesma aplicação realizando duas ou mais requisições ao mesmo tempo).

Comment: Eu já fiz diversos testes com esses parâmetros. Sim, realiza centenas de requisições.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução 'suja' (mas prática e que te dará tempo), seria diminuir o tempo entre recycle do pool que serve o wcf.

Neste meio tempo procurar o fornecedor para que junto consiga descobrir o que está acontecendo, já que pode ser desde um bug bobo no código da dll, até problemas mais sérios como 'gestão de concorrência'.